# Problem with requests containing domain and port

Tags: nginx, cloudflare

I have configured Cloudflare zero trust with my nas, linking my domain to my nas with tunnel.

Certain applications work fine and it is possible to access from the outside, but I have a docker that when accessing, internally makes requests to subdomain.mydomainexample.org:6768 and keeps thinking, since it never finds the route. Internally docker works with this port.

Is it possible to redirect this request to subdomain.mydomainexample.org? excluding the port, since I have configured nginx proxy manager so that when it looks for the domain subdomain.mydomainexample.org it takes it to the proper docker.

Thank you and I hope I have explained myself.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the custom port to be accessible on the Cloudflare edge side, then you need to use **[Cloudflare Spectrum](https://www.cloudflare.com/products/cloudflare-spectrum/)**. The default Cloudflare reverse proxy is enabled for a list of [standard ports](https://developers.cloudflare.com/fundamentals/get-started/reference/network-ports/), additional ports (such as 6768) can be opened but require Spectrum.

Or, you can accept the request on Cloudflare on any of the standard supported ports, and then configure your infrastructure so that it sends it to the correct listening port in your internal network.